# CSS classes for table percent heights and widths not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the rows and heights of a table as percentages using various classes but they do not seem to work. For some reason, the percentages are not being detected and I am not sure why.

I tried setting setting the table height and width to 100% but this causes table to be too wide and lose its height, so have it these both set to 650px.

```
table{
height: 100%;
width: 100%; 
height: 650px;
width: 650px;
border-style:hidden;
/* centre the table */   
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I also tried setting the body width and height to 100% as per other's suggestions but this had no effect.

```
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle is at:
http://jsfiddle.net/g9apxqgb/5/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you write `height: 100%; width: 100%;`, you must think about `100%` of what? If you set the `<section>` element which is the parent of your `table` to a height of, say, `400px`, then you will see the `table` element take up `100%` of that height.

Likewise, if you want the `table` to fill the entire screen, then you should start by setting the `html` or `body` element to have a `height` and `width` of `100%`.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9apxqgb/6/), the `html`, `body`, `main` and `section` elements have all a `height` and `width` of `100%.

```
html, body, main, section {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I've removed the original table height and code and set the section width and height to as follow but now the table is flattened - see http://jsfiddle.net/g9apxqgb/9/ - thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at my jsFiddle and try figure it out, I think that's the result you are looking for. This is a homework assignment and I'm sorry but that's as much help as I think you *should* get.